# iReport: localized default values for parameters

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

How to use localized default values for parameters in *iReport*?

Using a ***$R{message.key}*** as the parameter default value has negative consequences in the "Read fields" functionality of *iReport*'s SQL editor. More precisely, the following error is shown (after pressing the **Read fields** button in **Report query** dialog):

``` Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``$R{message.key}'' : Attempt to access property on undefined variable or class name ```

Any way around this *iReport* problem?

Here is the image to illustrate the problem:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a *iReport*'s bug.

You can temporary comment the ***defaultValueExpression*** expression and add the fields via the  **Report query -> Read fields** button.

Or you can manually add the fields declaration.

Comment: But this doesn't resolve the issue that "Read fields" in iReport's report query screen ceases to work once the `defaultValueExpression` has a `$R{..}` in it.

Answer (score 0):

This is iReport bug ! To solve this issue please follow the below steps.

1. Open XML File
2. Remove defaultValueExpression tag value.

[image]